# How can I see when the field changes alphabetically in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

So say I have a file in my mongo that has these documents in the CARS collection.

I know I can sort with this:   `db.cars.find().sort({car:1, price:-1})`

So I need a query that brings me back the top 1 car of each field of car . I want to `{$set:{"price_high"},{multi:true}}` to these 3 selections so that they have a new field of "price_high" added to those only.

```
'car':Chevy, 'price':100 //1 I need this one
'car':Chevy, 'price': 80 //2
'car':Chevy, 'price': 60 //3
'car':Lexus, 'price':99 //1 I need this one
'car':Lexus, 'price':90 //2
'car':Lexus, 'price':85 //3
'car':Maserati, 'price':99 //1 I need this one
'car':Maserati, 'price':96 //2
'car':Maserati, 'price':93 //3
```

MONGO TERMINAL QUERY ONLY IS NOT GOING INTO A FILE BUT INTO TERMINAL!!!!!!

Comment: You're only testing Mongo's commands in a terminal? Not writing them in a file?

Comment: Can't you use `distinct`? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: I was also thinking about `distinct`, but how to pick only the most expensive car of each make? `distinct` will pick one, not necessarily the most expensive one. It will return only `['Chevy','Lexus','Maserati']`.

Comment: @JeremyThille The problem with `.distinct()` is that it does not tell your "which" document was the one that has the "highest" price for that distinct value. There is another way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my point already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your introduction to MongoDB, what you are now looking for is the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. This is the MongoDB way of doing "GROUP BY" in SQL, and many other things that manipulate the data from it's original form.

To both get the results and "update" the data you now do something like this (ideally in bulk) :

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
    // Sort as required
    { "$sort": { "car": 1, "price": -1 } },

    // Group on the "first" entries per car
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$car",
        "doc_id": { "$first": "$_id" },
        "price": { "$first": "$price" }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc.doc_id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "price_high": true }
    });
    count++;

   // Empty per 1000 processed and re-init
   if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
       bulk.execute();
       bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
   }
});

// Clear any remaining
if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Of course you can always just pull out the three `_id` values ( or how ever many ) and use `$in` with `{multi:true}` on your update instead is you believe your real sample is small enough.

But the basic case here is to use `.aggregate()` to get those "top documents" ( [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) after [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) is the key here ) and then do whatever you have to do to update the results you get from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group aggregate function as below :

```
db.cars.aggregate(
[
{$group:
  {
  "_id": "$car",
  "price":{"$max":"$price"},
  "gid":{"$first":"$_id"}
  }
 }
 ]
  ).forEach(function(doc)
   {
   db.cars.update({"_id":doc.gid,"car":doc._id,"price":doc.price},
   {"$set":{"price_high" : true}});
 }
```

Comment: You might want to actually try that on some sample data to see the problem(s).

Comment: what problems are you getting ? you can use "$max" operator. there might be some syntax errors. try using "$max" opertor.

Comment: For one you are setting "all" cars of the same make with the new value (in fact you are setting every document in the collection per car make). Second your statement is not validly constructed in JSON notation. The big hint here is "just because they asked" to use `{ multi: true }` doesn't mean that's the right way to do it.

Comment: please check it again now. It was a typo :)

Comment: Typo is still there. Basic problem is still there also. Try it on the data as supplied and see the results. See the [answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30706032/3561036) for something that works.

Comment: can you explain me that basic problem please ?

Comment: Sure. You thought that `{ "$max": "$price" }` is a nice shortcut since it will return the maximum value for that grouping key for that field. The problem is it does not tell you "which" document is the actual one you need to update. Currently you are updating "all" of the same "car" makes with the new value, and the OP only asked for the "one" with the max price per car to be updated. You could do `db.collection.update({ "car": doc._id, "price": doc.price })`, but it's not really "guaranteed" to update only one document, especially using "multi". The real case is to get the `_id` of the doc.

Comment: And that edit is invalid as well. You need a grouping operator. You need the "first" document, and you "need" it after sort. Which is what I did. Just trying to teach you something.

Comment: {"_id":doc.gid,"car":doc._id,"price":doc.price} will update only correct document. even if doc.gid was not used, we are finding the one which is with highest price, and updating only that car. Not all the cars of same type.